# Why does Maven is looking in the wrong repo?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I'm trying to get the newest hibernate version for my project, for this purpose I've added the  jboss repo into my settings.xml

```
 <repository>
   <id>jboss-releases</id>
   <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
 </repository>
```

but when I do the depency search from my m2eclipse plugin I see only results from the official maven repo, why? Why I don't see the latest release 3.5.1? Instead only 3.3.2 is shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven isn't looking in the wrong repository and dependencies on hibernate 3.5.1 artifacts **are**  available in the JBoss repository (and get resolved).

However, m2eclipse is very likely not configured to use the Nexus index of the JBoss repository and you need to enable this index in your m2eclipse installation. This can be done from the **Maven Repositories** view. So open this view, unfold **Project Repositories** and **right-click** on the JBoss repository and select either **Enable Minimal Index** or **Enable Full Index**.

Instructions are available in [Maven Indexes view](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Maven+Indexes+view).

Comment: Thanks a lot Pascal! Can't appreciate it much enough I guess.