# why source package is empty when use maven's official repo?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, package, nexus

this issue is not the same as [Why does Maven is looking in the wrong repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032022/why-does-maven-is-looking-in-the-wrong-repo)

[image: the size of source package is too small ,no source file in it at all]

[image: i can open that source package, which means this is not because i download a broke source package.]

the size of source package is too small ,no source file in it at all

why i cannot find source code in the source package, it is confusing, i am sure it's not a broken source package, since i can open it, but why there is no java files in it?

Comment: The simple answer is: Because the maintainers decided not to do it.

Comment: @khmarbaise damed that maintainer:(

Comment: Check out [the source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/activemq/trunk/activemq-all/). It is simply a sum of all module dependencies and  has no source on its own.

Comment: @yorkw a sum of modues? i don't think so, since it is empty:(